# Assessing multiple Treatment Effects in Overlapping Interventions for difference-in-difference

Tags: difference-in-difference, causal-inference, treatment-effect

I am currently working on evaluating the impact of two sequential treatments, Treatment 1 and Treatment 2, on two distinct groups in our country: Group A and Group B. Treatment 1 is administered at time $t_1$, followed by Treatment 2 at time $t_2$, where $t_2>t_1$. Group B is subjected to Treatment 1(B changes to B^) and Treatment 2(B^ changes to B^^). It is noteworthy that Treatment 2 overlaps with Treatment 1 for Group B. Group A, on the other hand, remains untouched by either treatment.

In an attempt to quantify and compare the effects of these treatments on Group B relative to Group A, I have formulated a model:

$$ Y_{ijt} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \text{Group}_B + \beta_2 \cdot \text{Treat}_1 + \beta_3 \cdot \text{Treat}_2 \\ + \beta_4 \cdot (\text{Group}_B \times \text{Treat}_1)+  \beta_5 \cdot (\text{Group}_B \times \text{Treat}_2)\\ + \beta_6 \cdot (\text{Group}_B \times \text{Treat}_1\times \text{Treat}_2)+   \epsilon_{ijt} $$

where:

- $\beta_1$ captures the baseline difference in outcomes between Group B and Group A before any treatment.
- $\beta_2$ captures the effect of treatment 1 (going from B to B^) on Group B compared to Group A.
- $\beta_3$ captures the effect of treatment 2 (going from B^ to B^^) on Group B compared to Group A.
- $\beta_4$ captures the interaction effect of being in Group B and receiving Treatment 1.
- $\beta_5$ captures the interaction effect of being in Group B and receiving Treatment 2.
- $\beta_6$ captures the interaction effect of being in Group B, receiving both Treatment 1 and Treatment 2.

My primary concern is estimating $\beta_6$ as Treatment 2 overlaps with Treatment 1 for Group B. Given this overlap, I am seeking clarification on whether it is a meaningful and valid estimate. Moreover, am I correctly assessing this problem's framework or am I fundamentally making any mistake? Also, what are the causal inferences I can make in this model? Are there any resources that deal with this type of problem?